# Characters beyond Z in alphabetic order

Tags: java, sorting, compareto, alphabetical

Ok, this is just a quick question since I'm not able to find the answer myself. In lists of Strings that are ordered alphabetically, using the `Collections.sort` and `compareTo` functions, what is the last available character (beyond "ZZZ")?

I would like to know characters beyond "ZZZ" in `compareTo`'s order, out of curiosity.

Comment: To avoid null, why not use sorted set?

Comment: Your "Solution" is wrong by the way - it breaks the `comparator` contract when both values are null.

Comment: @Ordous Ah indeed, thanks a lot for pointing that out. Changed it.

Comment: You are comparing **Strings** not characters. The last `String`, i.e. the `String` for which no “greater” `String` exists, is a `String` consisting of 2147483647 repetitions of the character `'\uFFFF'`. You don’t want to use that…

Comment: Does anyone else get the impression that the question was edited after some of these responses were made?

Comment: @rcook Yeah, Joe removed all my pieces of code about my Sorting method so just the question remains.. Probably because I already have a solution for my sorting problem, which is not related to the original question found in the title. So he removed all the code and just left my last sentence there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote by Holger:

> You are comparing Strings not characters. The last String, i.e. the String for which no “greater” String exists, is a String consisting of 2147483647 repetitions of the character '\uFFFF'. You don’t want to use that…

I consider this as the correct answer to my question asked.

---

PS: For those wondering, this was the code in the original question:

Reason why I asked the question:

```
Collections.sort(myObjectList, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2){
        String name1 = o1.getName();
        String name2 = o2.getName();

        if(name1 == null)
            name1 = "ZZZ"; // <- Last String in compareTo's order
        if(name2 == null)
            name2 = "ZZZ"; // <- Last String in compareTo's order

        return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
});
```

Changed to the following instead to solve my issue:

```
Collections.sort(myObjectList, new Comparator<MyObject>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2){
        String name1 = o1.getName();
        String name2 = o2.getName();

        if(name1 == null && name2 == null)
            return 0;
        if(name1 == null) // && name2 != null
            return 10;
        if(name2 == null) // && name1 != null
            return -10;
        else // name1 != null && name2 != null
            return name1.compareTo(name2);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have to ask here - isn't there [already a `Comparer` for strings in Java?](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/strings/12stringcomparison.html)...  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: @Paul I have a list of MyObjects which I sort by their String name, so I'm not sorting the Name directly. If I would have a String-List of Names I could indeed just call `Collections.sort(myStringList);`, but in this case I have a List of MyObjects that I want to sort by their Name.

Answer (score 0):

In Unicode, the last character in the alphabet is `z` (lowercase).
First character that follows is `{`

Comment: UTF-8 has no order. UTF-8 is an encoding for the Unicode standard. That, however, has `{` right after `z`.